# IE11 Input type = Number

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I'm working with angular 4.3, I have an input field with input type number. I'm trying to restrict the user from entering any characters/letters. However, input type number is not fully supported and allows me to enter characters such as "ABCDEFG" within the input field. What would be the best approach to restrict letters?

```
<input type="number"/>
```

Comment: Seems strange, IE supports `number`. Usually browsers that don't support `number` fallback to `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `number` doesn't work, I usually suggest to go for `<input type="text" pattern="\d+"/>`.

You can of course change your pattern to anything number-related (like `(\d|[1-5]\d|60)` to set min to 0 and max to 60)

Comment: Doesnt work, I've tried it. Still allows me to enter characters in IE11

Comment: Apparently, even though marked as supported on the majority of support tables, IE11 seems to not "really" support `type="number"`. Regex don't work either? I'm astonished.